Confusion with xslt:apply-templates
I do not understand how apply-templates works in XSLT.
Now I have this XML document:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <occupation>Software Engineer</occupation>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jane Smith</name>
        <age>28</age>
        <occupation>Graphic Designer</occupation>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Sam Brown</name>
        <age>35</age>
        <occupation>Data Analyst</occupation>
    </person>
</people>


And this XSLT:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <!-- Output -->
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    
    <!-- Default template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--  Adding ages -->
    <xsl:template  match="person">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="./name/text()" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Adding names -->
    <xsl:template  match="age">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

When I run it, he result I get is this:
<html>
   <body>
      
      <p>John Doe</p>
      
      <p>Jane Smith</p>
      
      <p>Sam nkmk</p>
      
   </body>
</html>

Which is unexpected since I want both the names and the ages of the people, because i defined both templates.
In one of the answers to this question, the following is said the XSLT default template rules are defined in such a way that, by default, they will match the top node of the document and then recursively process each of the child nodes, all the way to the bottom, well fair enough, so technically one would expect that the person node is processed, then it's children, and since there is a template for age, the age should be added to the html, yet it doesn't. (Also, according to the first answer of this question, it should even print the name and occupation since i did not define a template that matches text, like so <xsl:template match="text()">).
All of this is very confusing to me given that i am new to XSLT.
Could you please explain to me what is going on here?

Well, if you match on xsl:template  match="person" and don't use xsl:apply-templates inside that template, how do you expect any children to be processed? Your code outputs the name and that is then all you can expect from your code. Of course, instead of using <xsl:value-of select="./name/text()" /> in the template for person you could simply use <xsl:apply-templates/> in there and have e.g. <xsl:template match="name | age"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template> (or try to output more p elements although paragraph nesting is not HTML.

Recommended reading: https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/

You are missing an important part of your quote, which is "by default".
Your template matching person overrides the default built-in template - and it does not apply templates to the age (or any other) child of person. Therefore the template matching age is never instantiated, and neither are the built-in templates that would otherwise process the other children of person.

Thank you for the answer. If I understand correctly from the link you provided, by default, every node is checked recursively starting from the root element, if no template is defined by the programmer, it checks if there are any templates defined for it's children, otherwise, it applies what the programmer defined, and it doesn't process the children of the node in question as it is expected from the programmer to define what should be done with the children.

That seems correct, at least for the element nodes (the rules are different for other node types). And the processing starts with the root (document) node, not the root element.
